# How to add entry to 'More' menu or top menu to add action on multiple selections?

Tags: xml, button, odoo, action, openerp-7

#### Goal

I want to create delivery from a selection of order lines, but I can't get the button to appear.
[image: add a create delivery button]

#### Module

```
compose_delivery_order/
├── delivery_order_button.py
├── delivery_order_button.xml
├── images/
│   └── delivery_order_button.png
├── __init__.py
├── __openerp__.py
├── order_to_invoice_create_delivery_button.py
├── order_to_invoice_create_delivery_button.xml ← I'm working on this
├── sale_order_button.py
└── sale_order_confirm_button.xml
```

#### XML `<record>`

```xml
<record id="action_sale_order_liquidar" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Liquidar</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_sale_order"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">self.some_custom_code(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids'), context=context)</field>
</record><record id="id_of_the_action_value" model="ir.values">
    <field name="name">Liquidar</field>
    <field name="action_id" ref="action_sale_order_liquidar"/>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.server,' + str(ref('action_sale_order_liquidar'))"/>
    <field name="key">action</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_sale_order"/>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
</record>
```

#### Python

```python
import logging
from openerp import netsvc
from openerp.osv import osv

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class sale_order_line(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    def some_custom_code(self, db_cursor, user_id, ids, context=None):
        logger.error('+ + + + + + sale_order_line -> some_custom_code + + + + + + ')
        return True


def some_custom_code(self, db_cursor, user_id, ids, context=None):
    logger.error('+ + + + + + some_custom_code + + + + + + ')
    return True
```

#### Question

How do I add the button ? Either to submenu of `[More v]` or next to `[Create] or Import`.

N.B.: I check it's imported in the `__openerp__.py`'s `data` section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need take care of below things while adding new menu on *More* menu.

- register form view
- register action view
- register *ir_values* (from where you want to display menu)
- give proper related *view_id* reference
- *target* attribute in action view
- give related name for *record* tag

Try with below code (add code on .xml file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="view_create_delivery_button" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Create Delivery</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Create Delivery" version="7.0">

                    <!-- Design Form or put your field here -->                
                    <footer>
                        <!-- Add button on footer of pop-up window -->
                    </footer>
               </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="action_create_delivery_button" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Create Delivery</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">sale.order.line</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_create_delivery_button"/>
            <field name="target">new</field>
            <field name="multi">True</field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.values" id="ir_values_create_delivery_button">
            <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order_line" />
            <field name="name">Create Delivery</field>
            <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
            <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' + str(ref('action_create_delivery_button'))" />
            <field name="key">action</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```