# How do I get an editable multilines layout in OpenERP?

Tags: view, odoo, openerp-7

I want to create *Delivery orders* [based on a selection of *order lines to invoices*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36285497/802365) (as shown below) with the possibility to adjust quantity used in the *delivery order*.

[image: add a create delivery button]

#### Expected UI

Looking around, I found a UI similar to want I want in `Delivery orders` > `More` > `Return Shipments` (cf. _stock/wizard/stock_return_picking_view.xml_).

[image: expected ui]

#### What I got

But I don't get the same result with my XML
[image: what I got]

*view.xml*

```
<record id="view_create_delivery_button" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Create Delivery</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order.line</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Create Delivery" version="7.0">
            <label string="Select the quantities to create."/>
            <group>
                <field name="order_id"/>
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="product_uom_qty"/>
                <field name="state" invisible="1" />
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="create_returns" string="Create delivery" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                or
                <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
            </footer>

        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

#### Question

How do I get this editable multilines layout?

Answer (score 2):

What you see in the *Return Shipments* wizard is a `one2many` field that related to `stock.return.picking.line` on it tree view with `editable=top` attribute.

I am assuming this is what you wanted:

```
<record id="view_create_delivery_button" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Create Delivery</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field> 
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Create Delivery" version="7.0">
            <label string="Select the quantities to create."/>
            <field name="order_line" >
                <tree editable="top">
                    <field name="order_id"/>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="product_uom_qty"/>
                    <field name="state" invisible="1" />
                </tree>
            </field>
            <footer>
                <button name="create_returns" string="Create delivery" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                or
                <button string="Cancel" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Note: This is just a sample of how to use the field many2one's tree view, you might need adjust to your on needs.