# Odoo Add action on top form view

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How I can add action at this place on the form

[image]

Comment: Possibly related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285497/how-to-add-entry-to-more-menu-or-top-menu-to-add-action-on-multiple-selections

Comment: @danidee, thank you. I'll try these recommendations.