# odoo 10 action menu button

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

Am working with Odoo 10 and I want two things:

1. Insert a button in the menu specified in the picture.[image]

Then the button,

2. Will execute some code that operates with the selected objects.

I would like to know how to insert the button and the best approach for point number 2.

Comment: These will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285497/how-to-add-entry-to-more-menu-or-top-menu-to-add-action-on-multiple-selections/36288917#36288917

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is the way to create a new menu in More menu.

**1. Need to create new action for that menu.**

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_id_1">
    <field name="name">action.name</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_id_1"/>
    <field name="domain">[]</field>
    <field name="context">{}</field>
    <field name="res_model">Current Model</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">new</field>
</record>
```

**2. Binding events to action**

The available type of events are following

- **client_print_multi** (print from a list or form)
- **client_action_multi** (action from a list or form)
- **client_action_relate** (action from a list or form)
- **tree_but_open** (action on the items of a tree)

You have to use the **client_action_multi** and define the **action_id** in value. See below example.

```
<record model="ir.values" id="ir_value_id">
    <field name="model_id" ref="module_name.model_<model_name>" />
    <field name="name">Create Delivery</field>
    <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
    <field name="value" eval="'ir.actions.act_window,' + str(ref('action_id_1'))" />
    <field name="key">action</field>
    <field name="model">model.name</field>
</record>
```

So, At the end you have new option under the more menu.

Comment: Hi, am new to Odoo and am struggling with it. I test this(https://pastebin.com/pzvPmpqm) but didn't work.

Another thing, I don't want to display a form when the user clicks the button, I want to extract data from the model and save it in a file then give the file to the user so he can download it.

Comment: This should be a comment to the answer by Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd.
In Odoo11 ir.values doesn't exist any more. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256246/odoo-v11-how-do-you-add-an-action-view-to-the-action-drop-down-menu