# odoo v11 - how do you add an action/view to the 'action drop down' menu

Tags: treeview, odoo-11

In previous versions of odoo, you could add an item to the 'more' drop down menu by creating an ir.values record.

This new option then became visible in tree views and within records.

This does not appear to work in V11.

How do you add an item to what is now called the 'action' drop down menu.

Comment: You may find the answer in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62876816/is-there-a-way-to-add-an-extra-action-to-the-action-menu-in-tree-view-in-odoo-12

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there may be a new field against actions to allow this link to be created directly on the action itself.

field: binding_model_id

e.g. within an ir.actions.server record:

```
<field name="binding_model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order_line"/>
```