# Is there a way to add an extra action to the action menu in tree view in Odoo 12?

Tags: python, treeview, odoo, wizard, odoo-12

i am searchin to add a new button that displays my wizard to the action button display in the tree view

My wizard works because i tested it individually, but i need to add it to the action button on the top and i do not know how

I tried to use the action.server but did not find any example that helped me

Thanks

Also i know that from Odoo 10 to Odoo 12 changed, thats why i have not found any clue.

Next are the examples i tried but not succed

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="enviar_evaluacion">
        <field name="name">enviar_evaluacion</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="vista_formulario_riesgo_para_evaluacion"/>
        <field name="domain">[]</field>
        <field name="context">{}</field>
        <field name="res_model">pdi.riesgo</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.server" id="accion_servidor_evaluacion">
    <field name="name">Enviar a evaluacion</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_pdi_riesgo_wizard_evaluacion"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
        object.enviar_a_evaluar(context.get('active_ids'))
    </field>
</record>
```

next try

```
<record model="ir.actions.server" id="menu_action_evaluacion">
    <field name="name">Enviar a evaluacion</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_pdi_riesgo"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
        action=pdi.riesgo.wizard.evaluacion.enviar_a_evaluar()
    </field>
</record>




<menuitem id="menu_enviar_a_evaluacion" 
          name="Enviar a evaluacion" 
          parent="pdi_Riesgo.menu_riesgo_evaluaciones" 
          action="menu_action_evaluacion"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "new" way is to set some new fields on actions. Following is an example from [Odoo's app crm](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/57261e5ae6bd0bd17efddf919dfe733895a61bb3/addons/crm/views/crm_lead_views.xml#L799-L814):

```xml
        <!--
            'Mark as Lost' in action dropdown
        -->
        <record id="action_mark_as_lost" model="ir.actions.server">
            <field name="name">Mark as lost</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_crm_lead"/>
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="crm.model_crm_lead"/>
            <field name="binding_view_types">list</field>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">
if record:
    action_values = env.ref('crm.crm_lead_lost_action').read()[0]
    action_values.update({'context': env.context})
    action = action_values
            </field>
        </record>
```

So there are three fields on model `ir.actions` (which is inherited by `ir.actions.server`) all beginning with `binding_`

- binding_model_id: set a ref to an existing model, is enough to show the action in the action menu
- binding_type: `report` for the report menu and `action` for the action menu (default)
- binding_view_types: `list,form` is default, `list` and `form` should also work, i didn't look into that field, so maybe there are way more combinations/values

Comment: in the <field name="code"> part, can i use a method that i have in a python file?? In a wizard.py file

Comment: Yes you can call methods of the model behind `model_id`, for example `model.my_method()` or if you have marked some records in the list view, you can also call `records.my_multi_method()`.

Comment: i will try this today. In the night i will comment again if it worked or not

Thanks for the help

Comment: The problem continues, eventhough no error is shown, the button does nothing. Here is the code now

Comment: <record id="action_enviar_a_evaluacion" model="ir.actions.server">
<field name="name">Enviar a evaluacion</field>
<field name="model_id" ref="model_pdi_riesgo_wizard_evaluacion"/>
            <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_pdi_riesgo"/>
            <field name="binding_view_types">list,form</field>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">
                if record:
                    action_values = records.pdi_Riesgo.pdi.riesgo.wizard.evaluacion.enviar_a_evaluar()
                    action = action_values
            </field></record>

Comment: the wizard have the enviar_a_evaluar method that is working, i try it as a solo button and works

Answer (score 0):

[Odoo 7,8,9 and 10] to add an action to the action menu, you must also create a record for the "ir.values" model. Here an example:

```html
<record model="ir.values" id="ir_values_my_action">
      <field name="model_id" ref="model_my_model" />
      <field name="name">Name Of Action</field>
      <field name="key2">client_action_multi</field>
      <field
        name="value"
        eval=
          "'ir.actions.server,' + str(ref('action_name_reference'))"/>
      <field name="key">action</field>
      <field name="model">my.model</field>
    </record>
```

Comment: That's a solution for older Odoo versions, but not working in Odoo 12, because that model `ir.values` isn't existing anymore.

Comment: You're right, I'll update my answer to add the related version where it works. Someone else has already written the solution for Odoo 12, related to the new **binding_model_id** property.

Comment: You can also add version 7, 8 and 9, because that solution should work there too. And yes i have written that other answer :-P