# How to confirm multiple sale order in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am new to python but I am willing to learn :)
Basically I need to have a menu for confirming multiple sale order in Odoo 10.

So far I found this [How to add entry to 'More' menu or top menu to add action on multiple selections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285497/how-to-add-entry-to-more-menu-or-top-menu-to-add-action-on-multiple-selections) However I am not sure if it is the same for Odoo 10.

I found this code in **sale.py**

```py
@api.multi
def action_confirm(self):
    for order in self:
        order.state = 'sale'
        order.confirmation_date = fields.Datetime.now()
        if self.env.context.get('send_email'):
            self.force_quotation_send()
        order.order_line._action_procurement_create()
    if self.env['ir.values'].get_default('sale.config.settings', 'auto_done_setting'):
        self.action_done()
    return True
```

if the above code is can be used for confirming multiple sale orders then all I need is to have extra menu which uses it.

Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module may help you https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/sale_order_mass_confirm/

It is available in  odoo apps.